# when to use Wait and when to use await?

Tags: word-choice

I am in a situation where i am expecting some data from my client. I want to write the same in a very polite manner that "i am expecting the data, even after my repeated intimations."

Here i wanted to use a sentence as

```
I'm just sending this mail to remind you that, currently i am awaiting for data.
```

I am confused i should use wait or await in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.englishpractice.com/vocabulary/difference-wait-await/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page15.shtml

The main thing is that 'await' is to be used with inanimate objects; and 'wait' is to be used with verbs and when referring to someone.

However, in the example you've given 'waiting' will be better.

**"I'm just sending this mail to remind you that, currently i am waiting for data."**

This is because though you're referring to data, the implicit meaning is that you're waiting for data from him/her.

If you're looking for a formal version, go for something like this:

**"This is a reminder that I'm yet to receive the data."**

Or

**"I've still not received the data even after repetitive demands/appeals."**

Comment: Based on your links, I don't think your answer is correct. Either wait or await can be used with inanimate objects. ("I am waiting for a bus.") And I don't understand "...'wait' is to be used with verbs...." Could you provide an explanation or example?

Comment: I was talking about the general means of usage @KenMohnkern. You can use either *Wait or Await* sparingly since English is a flexible language. However, *Await* generally is followed by an *object* and it's generally not referring to people but to inanimate things. Also, to address the wait part, "I've been waiting in line an hour to get tickets." If I'm confusing you sorry. Here are two other links I came across that shed further idea on my explanation. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8207/what-is-the-difference-between-wait-and-await         http://www.englishgrammar.org/wait-await/

Answer (score 0):

'Await' is more formal than 'wait' - it would be used in formal letters